water entering cone from the bottom- calculus
Water is being pumped into an inverted conical tank at a rate of 11.5
cubic meters per min.
The tank has height 8
meters and the diameter at the top is 6.5
meters.
Find the rate at which the water level is rising when the height of the water is 1.5
meters.
I found radius in terms of h: $r=\frac{3.25h}{8}$ and volume: $V=\frac{1}{3}π(\frac{3.25h}{8})^2(h)$.
How should i proceed??
thanks for any help!!

Your work so far is good. You are given the rate of change of the volume $V$, so you can use your equation for $V$ to work out the rate of change of the height $h$ when $h=1.5$. Specifically, work out what $dV/dt$ is in terms of $h$ and $dh/dt$, plug in $dV/dt$ and $h$, and solve for $dh/dt$.

$$V=\frac{1}{3}π\left(\frac{3.25h}{8}\right)^2(h)=\int_0^t \frac{dV}{dt}\cdot dt$$
Given that $\frac{dV}{dt}$ is constant ($11.5 \text{ m}^3/\text{s}$).
Putting this in the above equation gives:
$$V=\frac{1}{3}π\left(\frac{3.25h}{8}\right)^2(h)=(11.5)t\implies h=\left(\frac 3{\pi}\left(\frac 8{3.25}\right)^3(11.5)t\right)^{\frac 13}$$
Differentiating $h$ gives $\frac {dh}{dt}$ as:
$$\frac{dh}{dt}=\left(\frac 3{\pi}\left(\frac 8{3.25}\right)^3(11.5)\right)^{\frac 13}\frac 1{3t^{\frac 23}}$$
